# Stored procedure en LinQ c#

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedure, asp

Hola desarrolladores buen día, estoy con un problema resulta que mi proyecto no tiene que tener ningun **procedimiento de almacenado** en `SQLServer` y me pidieron hacer todo desde `linQ` el asunto es que no he encontrado cómo crear el procedimiento de almacenado en el codigo solo como llamar al procedimiento desde el mismo(Cosa que no me sirven porque me prohibieron ocupar `SP` en `SQL Server`).

acá tengo el codigo del SP que hice en el Sql obviamente ya lo borre del mismo y deseo saber como crear este mismo codigo en `C#` usando `LinQ`

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[sp_i_programa_semanal] 
(@BarNom varchar(50),
@Fecha datetime,
@h1 numeric (10, 4),
@h2 numeric (10, 4),
@h3 numeric (10, 4),
@h4 numeric (10, 4),
@h5 numeric (10, 4),
@h6 numeric (10, 4),
@h7 numeric (10, 4),
@h8 numeric (10, 4),
@h9 numeric (10, 4),
@h10 numeric (10, 4),
@h11 numeric (10, 4),
@h12 numeric (10, 4),
@h13 numeric (10, 4),
@h14 numeric (10, 4),
@h15 numeric (10, 4),
@h16 numeric (10, 4),
@h17 numeric (10, 4),
@h18 numeric (10, 4),
@h19 numeric (10, 4),
@h20 numeric (10, 4),
@h21 numeric (10, 4),
@h22 numeric (10, 4),
@h23 numeric (10, 4),
@h24 numeric (10, 4))

    As
    Begin
    Set nocount on

    Declare @codigo_barra int
    Declare @count_reg int
    --select * from tb_programa_semanal
    --sp_help tb_programa_semanal


    select @codigo_barra = codigo_barra
    from  tb_barra 
    where descripcion_barra = @BarNom

    select @count_reg = count(*) 
    from tb_programa_semanal 
    where codigo_barra = @codigo_barra
    and Fecha = @Fecha
    if (@count_reg = 0)
    Begin
            insert into tb_programa_semanal (Codigo_barra,Fecha,FP_h1,FP_h2,FP_h3,FP_h4,FP_h5,FP_h6,
                                            FP_h7,FP_h8,FP_h9,FP_h10,FP_h11,FP_h12,FP_h13,FP_h14,FP_h15,
                                            FP_h16,FP_h17,FP_h18,FP_h19,FP_h20,FP_h21,FP_h22,FP_h23,FP_h24)
            values (@codigo_barra,@Fecha,@h1,@h2,@h3,@h4,@h5,@h6,@h7,@h8,@h9,@h10,@h11,@h12,@h13,@h14,
                    @h15,@h16,@h17,@h18,@h19,@h20,@h21,@h22,@h23,@h24)
    End --fin if (@count_reg = 0)
    Else 
    Begin
        update tb_programa_semanal
        set FP_h1 = @h1,
            FP_h2 = @h2,
            FP_h3 = @h3,
            FP_h4 = @h4,
            FP_h5 = @h5,
            FP_h6 = @h6,
            FP_h7 = @h7,
            FP_h8 = @h8,
            FP_h9 = @h9,
            FP_h10 = @h10,
            FP_h11 = @h11,
            FP_h12 = @h12,
            FP_h13 = @h13,
            FP_h14 = @h14,
            FP_h15 = @h15,
            FP_h16 = @h16,
            FP_h17 = @h17,
            FP_h18 = @h18,
            FP_h19 = @h19,
            FP_h20 = @h20,
            FP_h21 = @h21,
            FP_h22 = @h22,
            FP_h23 = @h23,
            FP_h24 = @h24
        where codigo_barra = @codigo_barra
        and Fecha = @Fecha
    End --fin else



End --fin Create


GO

If exists (Select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'sp_i_programa_semanal')
Begin
  Select ' -- SP: sp_i_programa_semanal creado >>'
End
```

Una cosa que me falto agregar los datos para llenar ese `SP` vienen de un archivo excel que ya subí

Comment: La pregunta es, ¿qué has intentado? Realmente llevar este código a C# no requiere de un alto expertís pero vayamos por partes, ¿ya viste cómo hacer un `if` en C# o declarar una variable? En estructura es básicamente lo mismo, lo que cambiaría sería la sintaxis

Comment: estoy realizandolo con entities, no es el como hacerlo la pregunta basicamente es comparar tambien datos de un excel con otra tabla aparte de esa ese dato de excel al compararlo que me obtenga el codigo que esta en esa tabla y ese codigo compararlo con una fecha que tambien se rescata del excel y si esa fecha es igual actualizar el registro y si no existe codigo + esa fecha en el registro insertar ese registro del excel a la BBDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues tienes 2 opciones, utilizar codigo sql desde tu código o utilizar un ORM.

Yo no recomiendo el usar código sql en tu aplicación, hay gente que gusta pero a mi me parece que "ensucia" el codigo.

Si de todos modos quieres usar codigo sql, yo utilizaría un micro-orm como dapper, con el puedes enviar código sql al servidor y te puede mapear el resultado de la consulta a objetos ee tus clases.

La segunda opción, la del ORM, me gusta mas. Casi todos los ORMs soportan funciones CRUD (create, read, update, delete), aparte que algunos permiten utilizar linq para crear las queries, como Entity Framework.

El problema de los ORMs es que pueden ser mucho lío dependiendo del ORM, configurarlos y todo eso. Para evitar complicaciones yo utilizo una librería llamada Linq2db, trae todo lo necesario para crear consultas en linq, soporta funciones crud, no requiere mucho de configuración, y es bastante rápido.

En Linq2db, necesitas primero crear clases para cada tabla con la que vas a trabajar, algo así:

```
using System;
using LinqToDB.Mapping;

[Table(Name = "Products")]
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "ProductName"), NotNull]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // ... agregas una propiedad para cada columna...
 }
```

Ya que creaste todas las clases de cada tabla, creas una clase que hereda de DataConnection, esta clase es la que permite la conexión a la bdd y que permite crear consultas y utilizar métodos para agregar, modificar y eliminar registros. Ahí declaras cada tabla utilizando las clades que creaste anteriormente, algo así:

```
public class DbNorthwind : LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection
{
    public DbNorthwind() : base("Northwind") { }

    public ITable<Product> Product => GetTable<Product>();
     public ITable<Category> Category => GetTable<Category>();

     // ... le sigues con cada tabla...
}
```

Tiene varios constructores, en unos puedes pasarle directamente la cadena de conexión, o, como en el ejemplo que puse, le puedes pasar la cadena de configuración guardada en tu app.config. Es cosa que juegues un poco.

Por último, para utilizar todo esto, por ejemplo para realizar una consulta con linq:

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
     var query = from p in db.Product
                         where p.ProductID > 25
                         orderby p.Name descending
                         select p;

     return query.ToList();
```

}

O para actualizar registros:

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
    db.Product
       .Where(p => p.ProductID == product.ProductID)
       .Set(p => p.Name, product.Name)
       .Set(p => p.UnitPrice, product.UnitPrice)
      .Update();
}
```

Lo que hace Linq2db es convertir la expresión de linq en una consulta sql, se lo manda al servidor, el servidor regresa el resultado y linq2db mapea el resultado a tus clases. Puedes usar joins y varias cosas de sql desde linq.

Si te interesa échale un ojo: github.com/linq2db/linq2db

EDIT: También hay una forma de crear todas las clases y el DataConection automaticamente, por si tu bdd tiene muchas tablas,  este es el proyecto:

https://github.com/linq2db/t4models